# How to print or download the filtered query?

Tags: php, html

hello I'm super noob in web developing I have this project where in I would like  to print or download the filtered query.. here is my code

```
<form action="adminarchive.php" method="post">
From: <input name="from" type="text" class="tcal"/>
To: <input name="to" type="text" class="tcal"/>
<label for="select"></label>
<select name="status" size="1" id="status">
<option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
<option value="Cancelled">Cancel</option>
</select>
<input name="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
<input name="print" type="submit" value="Print Report" onclick="window.print()" />
</form><br />
<table width="589px" border="1px"><tr><th>Client</th><th>Item</th><th>Unit Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>TotalPrice</th><th>Date Ordered</th><th>Status</th><th>TrackNumber</th></tr>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$a = isset($_POST['from'])?$_POST['from']:"";
$b = isset($_POST['to'])?$_POST['to']:"";
$c = isset($_POST['status'])?$_POST['status']:"";
$rest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM delivered WHERE dateord BETWEEN '$a' and '$b' AND stats = '$c' order by dateord DESC");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rest)){
?>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#00FFCC" style="font-size:10px">
<td><?php echo $row1['customer']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row1['itemname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1['unitP']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row1['quant']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1['totalP']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row1['dateord']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1['stats']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row1['tracknumb']; ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
```

I would like to print the table by pressing the print button just the table. can I possibly print a certain part of a page?

Comment: Can you show us what output you would like?  Based on your comments to the answers, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: its like when you click the button a print dialogue will show printing the table with the filtered query above.. is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the browser's print function?  You can add css print styles to hide anything you don't want in the print view (i.e. make the form not print).

Comment: its because I want to have a printable report where in the filtered data was shown.. ill try to make a css..

Answer (score 0):

You should read about creating an outfile with your query results. And then you can simply call the link that the query was saved as and generate a download that way.

You can read about generating outfiles with your query here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

This can create a CSV file which could then be opened using excel or another program displaying a nicely organized report for you.